# I cannot see my VBA macro in 'run a script' selection box

Tags: vba, outlook

I copied the following code in my oulook VBE, from one of the VBA communities and amended it as per my need.
I can run it using F5 and F8. Now I would like to run this macro whenever I receive an email in folder1. 
I tried setting up a rule but I cannot see the macro listed in the 'run a script' selection box. 
I have already checked that

1. macro security setting are correct
2. macro is in a module not in a class

can you please tell me what is going wrong in the setting.

```
Public Sub SaveAttachments()

    Dim myOlapp As Outlook.Application
    Dim myNameSpace As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim myFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim yourFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder

    Dim myItem As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim myAttachment As Outlook.Attachment
    Dim I As Long

    Set myOlapp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set myNameSpace = myOlapp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set myFolder = myNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
    Set yourFolder = myNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)

    Set myFolder = myFolder.Folders("folder1")
    Set yourFolder = yourFolder.Folders("folder2")

    For Each myItem In myFolder.Items
        If myItem.Attachments.Count <> 0 Then
            For Each myAttachment In myItem.Attachments
                I = I + 1
                myAttachment.SaveAsFile "C:\arthur\test.csv"

            Next
        End If

        myItem.Move yourFolder

    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: The answer you got worked for me. If it worked for you then mark it as the solution.

Comment: Thought I would share here that current version of O365 ProPlus removed the ability to run a script as part of a rule. If you want to get that functionality back, you need to make a registry change, and for the time being that will still work but may be removed at some point in the future. I found the necessary information to do that [here](https://www.msoutlook.info/question/run-a-script-rule-action-is-no-longer-working-or-available)

Answer (score 25):

To be recognized as proper script macro for the Rule Wizard, the macro has to have the expected parameter:

```
Sub myRuleMacro(item as Outlook.MailItem)
```

[MSDN article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306108/en-us) (still valid for Outlook 2007/2010/2013/2016)

[Related article](http://www.slipstick.com/outlook/rules/outlooks-rules-and-alerts-run-a-script/)

[Article about enabling run-a-script rules](https://www.slipstick.com/outlook/rules/outlook-2016-run-a-script-rules/) otherwise disabled due to security reasons
(registry key `EnableUnsafeClientMailRules`).

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue today on a similar script after Office was upgraded to Version 1803 (Build 9126.2282). Removing the "Pubic" keyword from the sub did the trick. Not sure why, since has been working the other way for years.

I also had to re-add the reg key that had disappeared - EnableUnsafeClientMailRules.

Comment: I'm guessing you didn't mean "Pubic". Also, it is unclear what steps you took to solve your problem, and how this problem is the same as the question posed. Brevity is ok, but a good answer should be formatted such that it is clear how your advice applies, and why.