# Outlook Script to Remove Attachments through a rule

Tags: vba, outlook, outlook-2010

I am new to both VBA and this forum. To start off let me say that I have spent a considerable amount of time trying to find my answer both by doing and searching.

I need to create a script that I can add to my rules to delete attachments from certain emails. I found this code and thought It would help.

```
Public Sub deleteAttach(itm As Outlook.MailItem) 
Dim objAtt As Outlook.Attachment 
Set objAtt = itm.Attachments
objAtt.itm(1).Delete
End Sub
```

Now I can't seem to get this code working. After reading about it, i realized that the itm needs to be an object but somehow if I use `Public Sub deleteAttach(ByVal Item As Object)` The rule doesn't find my script.

I have also tried to change the code to `objATT.Delete`

Any help will be much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Please note that in order for Outlook to recognize your scripts to run as part of a rule then it must include a parameter of type Outlook.MailItem or Outlook.MeetingItem.  More on this [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17493565/1958691). If you found a solution below that worked, please mark one as a correct answer to help others.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it's missing the subroutine?  It's set to the 2nd item as the arrays start at index 0

```
Public Sub deleteAttach(itm As Outlook.MailItem) 
'Dim objAtt As Outlook.Attachment 
'Set objAtt = itm.Attachments 'AttachmentS collection
'objAtt.itm(0).Delete 'note the 0 starts the indexing
'or
'for each att in objAtt
'   att.Delete
'next
For j = itm.Attachments.Count To 1 Step -1
        itm.Attachments.Remove (j)
Next j
itm.Save  'Save the mail item without attachments
End Sub
```

Comment: When I run the above coed, I get the following error: Run Time Error '13' Type Mismatch. And this is where the Debugger shows the error: Set objAtt = itm.Attachments

Comment: Ah, I see the issue.  It's a collection versus an individual attachment.  I made some edits and try this now.

Comment: Thanks for your help, The code works without errors now, but it doesn't delete the attachment. I have only 1 attachment in the email that i am testing it against. Any clue?

Comment: In that case, we need to save it by adding itm.save before End Sub.

Comment: Still no luck, the attachment is still not getting deleted. I tried it on a different machine. Also tried with MsgBox, just to check if the code is getting saved, but the attachment is still there..

Comment: I commented out my deletes and went with the remove method.  Does that help?  [Remove Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb175155(v=office.12).aspx)

Comment: It still doesn't seem to be working. I guess the delete method was correct.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is never *reading* the deleted attachment to the item. You pull the attachment off but then forget to "set it" again.

Additionally, you need to use `Option Explicit` at the top of your code.

```
Public Sub deleteAttach(itm As Outlook.MailItem) 
Dim objAtt As Outlook.Attachment 
Set objAtt = itm.Attachments 'this creates a "new" attachment you then delete from
objAtt.itm(1).Delete 'This line makes no sense if you think about it
End Sub
```

Try the following:

```
Public Sub deleteAttach(itm As Outlook.MailItem) 
    itm.Attachments(1).Delete
    itm.Save    
End Sub
```

You will run into obscure Outlook problems similar to this if you don't get in the habit of doing "Save" after modifying emails programmatically.

Or, if you want to get rid of *all* attachments, you can iterate backwards through the list:

```
Public Sub deleteAttach(itm As Outlook.MailItem)
    dim i as integer
    for i = ubound(itm.Attachments) to lbound(itm.Attachments)
        itm.Attachments(i).Delete
    next i
    itm.Save    
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for help. When I try to run the code to get rid of all attachments, this is the error i get : Compile Error: Type Mismatch on UBound. Also on the first code that you provided, it doesnt delete the attachment.

Comment: Any further suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Open an item you think the rule should process and run deleteAttach_test.

```
Private Sub deleteAttach_test()
    Dim currItem As mailitem
    Set currItem = ActiveInspector.currentItem
    deleteAttach currItem
End Sub

Public Sub deleteAttach(itm As Outlook.mailitem)
    ' There is only one attachment in the mail
    itm.Attachments(1).Delete
    itm.Save
End Sub
```

Re: "The rule doesn't find my script."

You choose the script when you add "RunAScript" to the rule. If the mail is one that invokes the rule, the code has to run.

---

If there can be multiple attachments:

```
Private Sub deleteAttach_V1_test()
    Dim currItem As mailitem
    Set currItem = ActiveInspector.currentItem
    deleteAttach_V1 currItem
End Sub

Public Sub deleteAttach_V1(itm As Outlook.mailitem)
    Dim j As Long

    ' Delete in reverse, the highest numbered remaining item each time
    For j = itm.Attachments.count To 1 Step -1
       itm.Attachments(j).Delete   
    Next j
    itm.Save
End Sub

Private Sub deleteAttach_V2_test()
    Dim currItem As mailitem
    Set currItem = ActiveInspector.currentItem
    deleteAttach_V2 currItem
End Sub

Public Sub deleteAttach_V2(itm As Outlook.mailitem)
    Dim i As Long

    For i = 1 To itm.Attachments.count
        ' Delete the new first item each time
        itm.Attachments(1).Delete   
    Next i
    itm.Save
End Sub
```