# Run Script to Append Subject and Body of Email

Tags: vba, outlook, exchange-server, outlook-2013

I am [attempting to] learn how to write a script in Outlook that when a certain category is set on an email:

1. Append the Subject with " PROJ=5"
2. Append the Body with about 10 lines of text
3. Send email.

My goal is to mark an email with a category and forward the email to our ticketing system.

I'm not really having any luck with the samples I have found.

Samples (URL) I have tried (Copied code and updated relevant fields):

- [slipstick.com](http://www.slipstick.com/outlook/rules/run-script-rule-change-subject-message/)
- [social.technet.microsoft.com](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/4801de52-1c5e-46c9-a13c-ddfa4ea49dcb/auto-add-text-to-subject-line-for-emails-forwarded-using-rules?forum=outlook)

Comment: It would help if you share what you have tried.

Comment: Brian probably means code. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I've tried a bunch of samples found at these sites:

http://www.slipstick.com/outlook/rules/run-script-rule-change-subject-message/
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/4801de52-1c5e-46c9-a13c-ddfa4ea49dcb/auto-add-text-to-subject-line-for-emails-forwarded-using-rules?forum=outlook
http://www.outlookcode.com/threads.aspx?forumid=2&messageid=25999
http://www.vbaexpress.com/forum/showthread.php?47023-script-for-outlook-append-text-to-subject-forward-to-email-address-move-to-fold

Comment: [Run command not showing if VBA script requires any arguments be passed to it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52737924/run-command-not-showing-if-vba-script-requires-any-arguments-be-passed-to-it)

Answer (score 1):

> 1. Append the Subject with " PROJ=5"

**`MailItem.Subject Property`** - Returns a String indicating Outlook item. Read/write.

[Example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff865652.aspx)

```
Item.Subject = "PROJ=5" & Item.Subject
```

> 2. Append the Body with about 10 lines of text

Example

```
Dim olBody As String
olBody = "<HTML><BODY><P>Append the Body with about 10 lines of text</P>" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
                     "<P>Append the Body with about 10 lines of text</P></HTML></BODY>" & vbNewLine

 olForward.HTMLBody = olBody & vbCrLf & olForward.HTMLBody
```

> 3. Send / Forward Email

Example

```
'// 
Set olForward = Item.Forward
'// add Recipent
olForward.Recipients.Add "email@domain.com"
'// Send or your use .Dispaly 
olForward.Send
```

> Run a Script Rule

To use [Rule Wizard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17493093/i-cannot-see-my-vba-macro-in-run-a-script-selection-box), your macro has to have the expected parameter:

Example

```
Public Sub ItemForward(Item As Outlook.MailItem)
    
End Sub
```

[Helpful article in MSDN Outlook 2010 VBA](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee814736%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

Complete Code Test on Outlook 2010 VBA:

Please make sure your References are set to run action script **(Tools > References)**

```
Option Explicit
'// Run Action Script
 
Public Sub ItemForward(Item As Outlook.MailItem)
    Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim olForward As MailItem
    Dim olBody As String
    
    Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    
    '// Append the Subject
    Item.Subject = "PROJ=5 " & Item.Subject
    Item.Save

     Set olForward = Item.Forward
    '// add Recipent
    olForward.Recipients.Add "Test@mail.com"
    
        
    olBody = "<HTML><BODY><P>Append the Body with about 10 lines of text</P>" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
                         "<P>Append the Body with about 10 lines of text</P>" & vbNewLine & _
                         "<P>Append the Body with about 10 lines of text</P>" & vbNewLine & _
                         "<P>Append the Body with about 10 lines of text</P>" & vbNewLine & _
                         "<P>Append the Body with about 10 lines of text</P>" & vbNewLine & _
                         "<P>Append the Body with about 10 lines of text</P>" & vbNewLine & _
                         "<P>Append the Body with about 10 lines of text</P>" & vbNewLine & _
                         "<P>Append the Body with about 10 lines of text</P>" & vbNewLine & _
                         "<P>Append the Body with about 10 lines of text</P>" & vbNewLine & _
                         "<P>Append the Body with about 10 lines of text</P></HTML></BODY>" & vbNewLine

             
    '// Forward Email
    olForward.HTMLBody = olBody & vbCrLf & olForward.HTMLBody
    '// Send or your use .Dispaly
    olForward.Send
    Set olApp = Nothing
    Set olForward = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, but this did not solve my problem.  I should have provided some of the things I had tried in my original post. 

These just gave me the same samples that I cannot get to work.

Comment: @thunderchld what version outlook are you running?

Comment: I am using Outlook 2013

Comment: @thunderchld I was hoping someone with outlook 2013 will help, I have updated my answer with complete code that i tested on 2010 outlook and i sure it will work on 2013 if not then let know.