# Run command not showing if VBA script requires any arguments be passed to it

Tags: vba, outlook

I have an Outlook VBA script but it doesn't run if any arguments are to be passed to it.

This doesn't work:

```
Public Sub SaveOutlookAttachmentsToDisk(MItem As Outlook.MailItem)
    Dim oOutlookAttachment As Outlook.Attachment
    Dim sSaveAttachmentsFolder As String
    sSaveAttachmentsFolder = "\Document\FTP\"
    For Each oOutlookAttachment In MItem.Attachments
        oOutlookAttachment.SaveAsFile sSaveAttachmentsFolder & oOutlookAttachment.DisplayName
    Next
End Sub
```

This works:

```
Public Sub SaveOutlookAttachmentsToDisk()

End Sub
```

Comment: if i do any code without arguments its working

Comment: Can you describe how is it not working? Do you get an error message?

Comment: Are you passing the MItem to the sub when you call it?
Try to compile your project and it will tell you if you forgot something.

Comment: Same code i used last week and working in other pc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The run command can only be useful where code can run standalone. There is no point in making other code appear in the dialog box.

To use code that requires a parameter, in this case a mailitem object, you need a mailitem first.

You may run code that uses a parameter indirectly, from a button, like this.

```
Option Explicit

Sub runCodeThatRequiresParameter1()

    Dim currItem As mailItem

    ' First open an appropriate mailitem
    Set currItem = ActiveInspector.currentItem

    ' Pass item to SaveOutlookAttachmentsToDisk
    SaveOutlookAttachmentsToDisk currItem

End Sub


Sub runCodeThatRequiresParameter2()

    Dim currItem As mailItem

    ' First select an appropriate mailitem
    Set currItem = ActiveExplorer.Selection(1)

    ' Pass item to SaveOutlookAttachmentsToDisk
    SaveOutlookAttachmentsToDisk currItem

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that the first mothed has Item parameter as your provide, if so, you need to create a new rule, select the action for the execution of the script, select the script for this method, you can receive the message automatically save attachments to the disk. In addition, please check if is because that you don't create rules for outlook on these computers that causes they dont't work.

Comment: we can create rule after successful  creation of module only